# Retrieve First value from cell in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, csv

I am reading a CSV file and i created a request for a  dataframe via pandas and i got the following below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJZjt.png)

is there a way to retrieve the first values within the Genre column and create a new column with the first values retreived?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas offers a way to split up the value in the column into a list. From there you can select the first value. First of all I created a sample dataframe similar to yours:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column1':[100,200,300],
    'column2':[150,250,350],
    'Genres':['Action;Adventure;Sci-Fi','Action;Adventure;Sci-Fi',None]
})

print(df)
```

It looks like this:

```
   column1  column2                   Genres
0      100      150  Action;Adventure;Sci-Fi
1      200      250  Action;Adventure;Sci-Fi
2      300      350                     None
```

Then you can use this line of code to split the string in the column `Genres` at `;` and put the first value in a new column called `first_genre`:

```
df['first_genre'] = df['Genres'].str.split(';').str[0]
```

Output:

```
   column1  column2                   Genres first_genre
0      100      150  Action;Adventure;Sci-Fi      Action
1      200      250  Action;Adventure;Sci-Fi      Action
2      300      350                     None        None
```

The value `None` in the third row only demonstrates that this method also works if the genres are not always present.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much! i apologize for the original message was my first time posting!

Comment: You're welcome! If I solved your question you can mark the answer as accepted.